# A java apprentice trying to migrate from System.out.println to swing

Tags: java, swing, console

I'm finally trying to migrate my old console programs to Swing, to make distribution to my friends easier. To this end, I'm trying to write a class ConsoleFrame that I can extend instead of JFrame, that will allow me to interface my old code with Swing as effortlessly as possible. out(String) appears to be working, but inln() has me stumped.

```
//Imports not included
public class ConsoleFrame extends JFrame
{
    protected JTextField in;
    protected JTextArea out;

    public ConsoleFrame(){
        this("Console Frame", 80, 10);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(int cols){
        this("Console Frame", cols, 10);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(int cols, int rows){
        this("Console Frame", cols, rows);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(String title){
         this(title, 80, 10);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(String title, int cols, int rows){
        in = new JTextField();
        in.setEditable(true);
        in.setColumns(cols);

        out = new JTextArea();
        out.setEditable(false);
        out.setColumns(cols);
        out.setRows(rows);
        out.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        setTitle(title);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(in, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(out, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pack();
    }

    protected void out(String o) {
        out.append(o);
    }
    protected void outln(String o) {
            out(o + BIO.$ln);    //BIO.$ln == System.getProperty("line.separator")
    }

    /*
     * This is supposed to halt execution until the user presses enter, then return the text entered in the JTextField named in.
     */
    protected String inln() {
        in.setEnabled(true);
        KeyListener enter = new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
                if(paramKeyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                     if(in.hasFocus()) {
                         in.setEnabled(false);
                     }
                }
            }
            @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {}
            @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {}    
        };
        in.addKeyListener(enter);
        while(true){    //This loop is intended to interrupt flow until in.isEnabled()==false, which will only happen when the enter key is typed.
            if(in.isEnabled()==false){
                String result = in.getText();
                in.setText("");
                in.setCaretPosition(0);
                this.removeKeyListener(enter);
                in.setEnabled(true);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tester program:

```
public class Tester extends ConsoleFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tester();
    }
    public Tester() {
        super("Test", 60, 30);
        out(inln());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it will fix your problem, but you should NOT be using a KeyListner.

JTextField was designed to use an ActionListener to handle the Enter key.

Comment: How would I go about this? I'm very very new to Swing. Something with instanceof and a cast to KeyEvent, maybe?

Comment: Start with the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. The section on `How to Write an Action Listener` might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of debugging shows the key code is 0x0 always. Replacing `keyTyped` with the following code seems to work;

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
    if (paramKeyEvent.getKeyChar() == '\n') {
        if(in.hasFocus()) {
            in.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I'm not saying this is a solution I'm overly happy with, but it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Oddly, it seems to work when I step through it in the Debug perspective, but not when I run it normally.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `keyListener` to the frame, and not the `in` textfield. Therefore, the event will always be captured by the textfield and never propagated up to the Frame. This is why you are not receiving the event.

Comment: Edited, but it doesn't appear to have worked.

I run the program, and enter "hello", and press the enter key. Nothing appears to happen. The text in _in_ remains the same, is not cleared, and nothing appears in _out_

Answer (score 0):

That `inln` code looks racy to me. To make it more robust:

- Change your code so that the actual program runs in a thread different from the event dispatch thread (I am not sure if this is already true). `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread` should return false when called from your test program.
- Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` in your output methods so that the actual output will happen on the event dispatch thread asynchronously.
- in `inln()`, use synchronization and `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` to initialize your key listener stuff (or use an `ActionListener` as already stated). Then use `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()` instead of your busy-waiting loop while waiting for input (laptop users' batteries will thank you for that, and the Task Manager which will no longer show 100% CPU usage).

---

Sorry, Here is the (tested and working) code for you:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ConsoleFrame extends JFrame
{
    private Object lock = new Object();
    private String enteredText = null;

    protected JTextField in;
    protected JTextArea out;

    public ConsoleFrame(){
        this("Console Frame", 80, 10);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(int cols){
        this("Console Frame", cols, 10);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(int cols, int rows){
        this("Console Frame", cols, rows);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(String title){
         this(title, 80, 10);
    }
    public ConsoleFrame(String title, int cols, int rows){
        in = new JTextField();
        in.setEditable(true);
        in.setColumns(cols);

        ActionListener enter = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                in.setEnabled(false);
                synchronized(lock) {
                    enteredText = in.getText();
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
                in.setText("");
            }
        };
        in.addActionListener(enter);

        out = new JTextArea();
        out.setEditable(false);
        out.setColumns(cols);
        out.setRows(rows);
        out.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        setTitle(title);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(in, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(out, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pack();
    }

    protected void out(final String o) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                out.append(o);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void outln(String o) {
            out(o + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    /*
     * This is supposed to halt execution until the user presses enter, then return the text entered in the JTextField named in.
     */
    protected String inln() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                in.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        synchronized(lock) {
            enteredText = null;
            while (enteredText == null) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
            return enteredText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I lack the experience. I can't do Swing, much less Synchronization. I'll try to fix it as I become more experienced, but for now it's beyond my ability.

Comment: Courtesy of Reddit, I've found a solution that addresses the issues you mention, and discovered CountDownLatch, which should be a good entry point for me to begin learning synchronization.

Comment: Added (tested and working) code to my answer. Hope this helps.